# MemoryMappedFile doesn't work with 2 processes?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, memory-mapped-files

I've made a simple test with a `MemoryMappedFile` as [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267552.aspx) says :

2 processes, 1 memory mapped file :

- the first process adds the string "1"
- the first process waits
- the second process adds the string "2" and terminates
- the first process now reads the whole memory mapped file

### process A:

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 10000))
            {
                bool mutexCreated;
                Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "testmapmutex", out mutexCreated);
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    writer.Write("1");
                }
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                Console.WriteLine("Start Process B and press ENTER to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                mutex.WaitOne();
                using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
                {
                    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    Console.WriteLine("Process A says: {0}", reader.ReadString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Process B says: {0}", reader.ReadString());
                }
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
```

### process B:

```
 using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap"))
                {
                    Mutex mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("testmapmutex");
                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(1, 0))
                    {
                        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                        writer.Write("2");
                    }
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
```

The result is :

[image]

Hu ?

Where is "1", "2" ?

However, if I run **ONLY** the first process ( without activating process B) I get :

[image]

What am I missing ?

I expect to see :

```
Process A says: 1
Process B says: 2
```

Comment: In the example from MSDN they write numbers, you write strings. The offset passed to CreateViewStream could be wrong! This will explain the garbage returned by the BinaryReader

Comment: @Steve they didnt conside any offset... and i just changed bool to string..

Comment: However, if memory serves, UTF8 is two byte and you write the second string starting at byte 1 overwriting be second byte of the first string.

Comment: @steve the 8 in utf8 is the number of bits per character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are battling an implementation detail of BinaryWriter.Write(string).  It writes the length of the string first, required so that BinaryReader knows how many characters it needs to read when reading the string back.  For short strings, like "1", it writes a single byte to store the length.

So the offset you pass to CreateViewStream() is wrong, passing 1 will make it *overwrite* part of the string written by process A.  The smiley character you see is the glyph for (char)1.  The length byte of the string written by process B.

Memory mapped files are troublesome in managed code.  You normally read and write to them by declaring a struct to set the layout and using pointers to access the view but that requires unsafe code.  Streams are a pretty poor abstraction for a chunk of memory but a necessary evil.  Also the reason it took so long for MMFs to become available in .NET.

Comment: You should not write code like this.  An obvious failure mode is when A writes a longer string than B counts on.

Comment: thanks for replies , if i write on A `writer.Write("1");` - you are actually telling me to read from appropriate index on B. but how would i know the index ?

Comment: And that's exactly the point.  MMFs only work well when the memory they map is carved up predictably.  Think structs with only value types.  If you actually want to implement streams with unpredictable lengths then a pipe is a much better alternative.  You can however make this work by letting A write the length.  B can read it and know where to write.  You'll need two views.

Comment: hans but when i put `1` and `2` as integers - - it also didnt work and they both  - same size...?

Comment: Hans ! with ints i can see it working :) in A i wrote `1` and in B I skpped 4 bytes ( as int) and all is well. now i will try with strings...( how can i know the length ? is xxx.length is enough ?  - in non unicode...)

Comment: hans ive just tested with string. all is OK. the problem was in B.  - the start offset . thank you very much :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's not clear. So you used at end `2` like an offset for `ProcessB`?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I noticed one apparently strange thing in the code of `ProcessB`. This code

```
using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream(1, 0))
```

creates a view from the *first* byte, but the strings in `.NET` are 2 bytes. I think it should be enough to you to make that `1->2` become 2. So the offset of the `ProcessB` view from the start of the mapped file will be *after* already inserted "1" string from `ProcessA`.

In your case *seems* that you *overlap* them.

Hope this helps.