# Calc utf-8 string size in bytes?

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0

I have a string of `utf8`.

I need to get its size.  ( bytes)

Does it always `x2` ? *// I mean multiply by 2*

is there any .net function for this ?

p.s.

*im asking this question becuase of my latest [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760073/memorymappedfile-doesnt-work-with-2-processes/9760573#comment12421178_9760573)
...I need ( in mempry mapped file) to calc the offset of a string ( utf8 )  - from another process..*

Comment: "I have a string of utf8." - not in .NET. You either have a string (which is UTF-16), or you have an array of bytes which represent a UTF-8 encoded string. In the latter case you can just use `Array.Length`.

Comment: With the "x2" thing... Are you sure you aren't using UTF-16?

Comment: @Porges does each char is represented in 2 bytes  - even if its from 0..127 ascii table ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: yes, this is the case with UTF-16. In addition, some characters will require 4 bytes instead of two. You can read more about UTF-16 on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No, it is not always x2 for UTF-8 and changes based on the actual contents. For ASCII characters it is 1 byte, but can go into several bytes for large code-point values. You want:

```
string s = // your string
int len = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s);
```

Comment: thanks marc...... ( please look at my edit - to see where this comes from... and why did i ask it:) )

Comment: @Royi then you might want to use the overloads that accept byte*, but it depends on the exact scenario

Comment: @MarcGravell sorry, seems that i dont understand you... lets say i have a string which contains regular chars(0..127) and special chars. ... something like this : `string s  = "abcאבג";` now - lets say  i want to go to the end of the location IN THE MEMORY....how can i calc **how many bytes to offset** ( mmf...) ?

Comment: @MarcGravell should `Encoding.GetByteCount(str)` is fine? does he know how to do it ?( my scenario...)

Comment: @Royi in which memory? unless you do `GetBytes()`, it isn't encoded *anywhere* - you just have the UTF-16 code-points. And they are always 2 bytes per character. So... `2 * s.Length` bytes. If you are going to encode later, then yes `GetByteCount` will tell you how much space to leave.

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi let me rephrase...:)...john wrote to a memory mapped file a string.(`"abcאבג"`). now paul wants to append one charcter to the end of the string ( also in the memorymapped file)...in order to do that he must go to the last location in memory where it ends. Does paul needs to calculate a strict calculation : `2*str.length` ? one more thing... Maybe john wrote to memory in utf8 (optimized)... so how paul will know how many bytes to bypass ? (in order to append his own char? ) ? please explain...:) thank you so much.

Comment: @RoyiNamir it depends how John wrote ;p If he wrote UTF-8 encoded data, then yes - `UTF8.GetByteCount` is the thing to use. If he copied the unicode code-points (UTF-16), then `2 * str.Length` (or Unicode.GetByteCount) would work.

Comment: How does this method perform as compared with a normal size()?

Comment: Should I ask, how many memory I will need to run this code?  I see this code in the implementation `char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();` - new array will be allocated?

Comment: @AlexShestakov `ToCharArray()` will always (except for empty strings) allocate a new array, because strings and arrays are different things; if you want a zero-alloc array-like-thing: you can use `.AsSpan()` instead, which gives you a "span" over the existing data, without any allocation; a span can be sliced into pieces (think "substrings") with zero allocations

Comment: That means what if my string is very long, I will have more problems with the memory. So, the more effective way is to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str.AsSpan())` which should not allocate more arrays into the memory

Comment: @AlexShestakov what's wrong with `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(str)` ? that doesn't allocate